# How to alter text of label based on if the text would overflowing - in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, measure

I have a UI requirement for displaying the user name list like the ones that appear on social media posts for displaying people who liked the post.

The problem in it is the overflow thing.

if it's a single user. Simply display them.

[image]

If it's a long list and overflows the label length then out the overflowing user names has to removed and replaced with remaining user count text.

[image]

Since I search through web and found no Xamarin Forms way of doing this. I am thinking of creating a custom renderer for this and using native text measuring API to figure the text to be displayed.

*Android*

```cs
var textSize = paint.MeasureText(this.Control.Text);
```

*iOS*

```cs
NSAttributedString nS = new NSAttributedString(txt, font: this.Control.Font);
var textSize = nS.Size;
```

Am I in right path? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: it seems ok, but maybe wouldnt it be better to never let more than one or two users to show on screen? i dont know how much space you have, but it doesn't seem much so better to simplify

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais The width of the label is the width of the screen, which changes with the device, and orientation. To show the number of users is necessary and important in my case.

Comment: this approach works as long as the username length is not large enough. what if the username length was long? A better approach IMHO is to put the number of users at beginning and user ellipses at the end of the texts ( i.e truncate the text on specific lenght).